# Grab fails to connect forced SSLv3 in the server

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to connect 'https://myvodafone.vodafone.in/myvodafoneselfcare/jsp/commons/login.jsp' using grab(version 0.4.8). I'm getting following error.

```
ERROR:in_vodafone:17162:375: (<class 'grab.error.GrabNetworkError'>, GrabNetworkError(35, 'error:140773E8:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1000)'), <traceback object at 0x10277cb00>)
DEBUG:in_vodafone:17162:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "in_vodafone.py", line 308, in download
    g.go('http://www.vodafone.in/pages/myvodafone.aspx')
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grab-0.4.7-py2.7.egg/grab/base.py", line 306, in go
    return self.request(url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grab-0.4.7-py2.7.egg/grab/base.py", line 384, in request
    self.transport.request()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grab-0.4.7-py2.7.egg/grab/transport/curl.py", line 345, in request
    raise error.GrabNetworkError(ex[0], ex[1])
GrabNetworkError: [Errno 35] error:140773E8:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1000)
```

my script contains following code:

```
from grab import Grab
g = Grab()
g.setup(hammer_mode = True, hammer_timeouts = ((100, 200), (300, 400), (500, 600)))
g.go('https://myvodafone.vodafone.in/myvodafoneselfcare/jsp/commons/login.jsp')
```

I found that there's a solution for urllib to fix this in http://bugs.python.org/issue11220. how can I use this solution with grab utility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found following solution and it worked fine.

```
from grab import Grab
import pycurl

g = Grab()
g.transport.curl.setopt(pycurl.SSLVERSION, 3)
g.setup(hammer_mode = True, hammer_timeouts = ((100, 200), (300, 400), (500, 600)))
g.go('https://myvodafone.vodafone.in/myvodafoneselfcare/jsp/commons/login.jsp')
```